# Stylesheet does not capitalize Polish letters correctly

Tags: unicode, capitalization

I'm using [SIAM's stylesheet (siamart.cls)](https://www.siam.org/journals/tex/siamart.cls), and the stylesheet doesn't seem to correctly capitalize the Polish `ł` to an `Ł`.

```
\documentclass{siamart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Title Łitłe}
\author{Authør Łauthør Thorłør}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Polish error example]

It correctly capitalizes the `ø` to an `Ø`.  I've also tried using '\l' and '\L'.

**Question:**  *Is the error on my side, or on the stylesheet's side?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the issue is in the class file, which uses `\uppercase` for the case changing rather than `\MakeUppercase`. A fix:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@ucnt#1\thanks{\MakeUppercase{#1}\futurelet\@tempa\@ucnta}
\makeatother
```

The difference here is that `\uppercase` is a TeX primitive and can only case change 'native' input for the engine, whereas `\MakeUppercase` is set up to deal with a range of additional macro-based entries, including `\l`.

Comment: There are a few more places where the class uses `\uppercase` instead of `\MakeUppercase`, which can also have adverse effects on non English documents.

Comment: @egreg Probably: I didn't pursue all possible cases

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient to set the input encoding. For correct uppercasing you also have to set TeX's internal encoding (which is in classical TeX and LaTeX identical to the font encoding) by choosing

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually have this in my full document, but that does not help.  As you can see in the picture, the letter Ł does indeed exist, but ł isn't capitalized correctly.